# Make html text input php variable

Tags: php, html

I want a html text input with `name="input1"` become a php variable called `$value`. I tried doing:

```
<html>

<form action="added.php" method="post" />

  <p>Send a message to JANNES database: <input type="text" name="input1" />
    </p>
   <input type="submit" value"Submit" />

</form>

</html>

<?php

$value = $_POST["input1"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO janne (String) VALUES ('$value')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('vajsing: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

And it is working, but I get this annoying error when I visit the website:

> "Notice: Undefined index: input1 in C:\wamp\www\added.php on line 26
>   Call Stack
>   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0008  250336  {main}( )   ..\added.php:0"

Notice that i didn't post the whole code. My php file is called added.php.

Comment: Whoah.... Please read up on SQL Injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

By default, `$_POST["input1"]` is empty as you have not submitted your form yet. You should check whether the form is submitted or not, like below:

```
if(isset($_POST["input1"])){
    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the form is submitted or not. If you load the page directly, there's nothing inside `$_POST['input1']`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$value = $_POST["input1"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO janne (String) VALUES ('$value')";
if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('vajsing: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This is probably the best way except he doesn't name his submit button so it won't be in $_POST and therefor doesn't answer the question without a suggestion of adding a name

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["input1"])){
    $value = $_POST["input1"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO janne (String) VALUES ('$value')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('vajsing: ' . mysql_error());
}

}
?>
```

The problem is: You weren't checking to see if it was set before trying to use it, so when you visit it without the post data being set then it gives you an error.